# Select rows which ocured in other specific table as foreign key the most

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table for Operator:

```
+--------------------------------+
|   ProviderID  | ProviderName   |
+---------------+----------------+
|        1      |   Movistar     |
+---------------+----------------+
|        2      |   Vadafone     |
+---------------+----------------+
|        3      |   Orange       |
+---------------+----------------+
```

And also I have this table of Plans those Operators provide. (simplified version):

```
+--------------------------------+
|   PlanID      |   ProviderID   |
+---------------+----------------+
|        1      |   2            |
+---------------+----------------+
|        2      |   2            |
+---------------+----------------+
|        3      |   2            |
+---------------+----------------+
|        4      |   1            |
+---------------+----------------+
|        5      |   3            |
+---------------+----------------+
```

I would like to print only those Providers who has the most Plans. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT O.ProviderId, COUNT(Pl.ProviderId) as numberOfPlans
FROM Plan Pl
INNER JOIN Provider O ON O.ProviderId= P.ProviderId
GROUP BY O.ProviderName
```

And this prints all the provider names and number of plans they have while I need to print only those that has the most plans, so in this case it would be only Vadafone which has 3 plans. (If other provider had same maximum value of plans it would be printed out as well).
Sorry for question, didn't know how exactly I should specify the problem.

Comment: I imagine I should use MAX() function somewhere, but can't figure out where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server you can use `TOP`.  For instance, to get one of the providers with the most plans:

```
SELECT TOP 1 pl.ProviderId, COUNT(*) as numberOfPlans
FROM Plan pl
GROUP BY pl.ProviderId
ORDER BY numberOfPlans DESC;
```

In other databases, this would usually be:

```
SELECT pl.ProviderId, COUNT(*) as numberOfPlans
FROM Plan pl
GROUP BY pl.ProviderId
ORDER BY numberOfPlans DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

or:

```
SELECT pl.ProviderId, COUNT(*) as numberOfPlans
FROM Plan pl
GROUP BY pl.ProviderId
ORDER BY numberOfPlans DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If there are ties, then in SQL Server you can do:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES pl.ProviderId, COUNT(*) as numberOfPlans
FROM Plan pl
GROUP BY pl.ProviderId
ORDER BY numberOfPlans DESC;
```

Notes:

- You don't need the `JOIN` to the `Provider` table, because the `ProviderId` is in the `Plan` table.
- The `GROUP BY` condition should be the same as the column in the `SELECT`.

Comment: The thing with TIES was exactly what I needed, thank you. speaking about INNER JOIN I think needed it to print out not the id of provider, but the name, which is in operators table.

Answer (score 0):

`order by` the `numberOfPlans` like

```
SELECT O.ProviderId, 
COUNT(Pl.ProviderId) as numberOfPlans
FROM Plan Pl
INNER JOIN Provider O ON O.ProviderId= P.ProviderId
GROUP BY O.ProviderName
ORDER BY numberOfPlans DESC;
```

Comment: This actually gives exactly the same result as code I gave that I have :)